# Windowed Chrome/Chromium and spacing above tabs

Tags: google-chrome, chromium

In tiling window managers (exhibited in Windows, and Linux (KDE, Gnome, probably others)), while Chrome/Chromium is "maximised" tabs touch the top of the screen without spacing, however, when windowed, a spacing of around 20px appears between the top of the tabs and the top of the window.

Is there any way, with an extension or otherwise, to remove this spacing while Chrome/Chromium is windowed?

Comment: You might want to [edit] the question and tell us **which** OS and window mangers you are referring to ...

Comment: This seems like a high-level GUI issue that would be implemented differently under different windowing systems, i.e. the code would be written differently for Windows, X11 (possibly also Wayland), etc. It seems like a fundamental design decision which would be difficult to reverse.